# Implementation of Qt's QTcpSocket ReadyRead signal

Tags: c++, qt, sockets, qtcpsocket

I want to know about Qt's implementation of `QTcpSocket`'s `ReadyRead` signal. How is it implemented on Windows and on Linux? Using `select()`, `poll()`, `epoll()`, `SIGIO` or any other way? How does `QTcpSocket` know when to emit a `ReadyRead` signal?

Comment: Hi, I deleted the second part of your question, I hope it's not a problem. You should post it as a separate question instead.

Answer (score 2):

Since Qt is open-source, you can look at the source code directly, and see for yourself.

They even have it [posted online](https://github.com/qtproject/qtbase/tree/dev/src/network/socket).

The OS-specific parts are (I think) implemented in [qnativesocketengine_unix.cpp](https://github.com/qtproject/qtbase/tree/dev/src/network/socket/qnativesocketengine_unix.cpp) and in [qnativesocketengine_win.cpp](https://github.com/qtproject/qtbase/tree/dev/src/network/socket/qnativesocketengine_win.cpp).

Comment: I'm pretty sure you won't find answers in the code for Linux, since it seems to be integrated into the gtk+ eventloop and use whatever gtk+ uses.

Comment: FYI, Qt has nothing at all with GTK+ eventloop

Comment: So where is the place (line numbers)? You gave an answer and many people read it. It's more efficient if someone searches once... (yeah, on it)